# Font used for attachment title

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, attachments

When I add an attachment to any document in Word 2010 the font used for the title has changed.  I am not talking about adding a caption but the title that is shown automatically as part of the attachment icon:

[image]

Anything which I attached before today is still showing with the correct font but any new items use a different font. This affects all types of attachments (for example, .msg, .xml, .css).

I don't know what I have done to alter the behaviour. How can I change the font back to the default please?

Comment: Add the photo and I will edit your post so it's embedded for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question although it's not a full answer.

I rebooted today (I really should have done that yesterday); having done so, any new attachments that I then added had the correct font.  I had to remove and reattach those from yesterday as they still had the wrong font.

I don't know what caused the corruption yesterday; I have posted this workaround in case anyone else experiences this issue in the future and finds this question.